# Unable to remove "orphaned" Clutter folder from Outlook 365 App (Version 2105)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

Clutter is a discontinued feature and the folder is now gone in Outlook web app, but on my installed version of Outlook the empty folder is still there with no apparently way to delete it. I tried using scanpst.exe on my .ost file to scan/repair corruption, but the folder persists. Does anyone know how to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright I finally found a solution but it is not completely intuitive. Since Focused Inbox was initially created as an alternative to the Clutter folder, if you temporarily turn on the Focused Inbox Feature (View -> Show Focused Inbox) the Clutter folder immediately disappears. You can then toggle Focused Inbox off again and Clutter will remain gone since the feature has been discontinued.

Comment: We first disabled the Clutter feature using Powershell (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/email/configure-clutter) and then we toggled Focused Inbox On/Off to get rid of the Clutter folder.  I am not sure if we could have just toggled Focused Inbox to both disable Clutter and get rid of the folder.

Answer (score 3):

Did you turn off the Clutter [in Outlook on the web](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-off-on-clutter-in-outlook-a9c72a77-1bc4-40e6-ba6d-103c1d1aba4c?ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US)?

If so, as I know, the Clutter folder remains in Outlook. It's by design.

[image: screenshot]

Based on my research and test on my Outlook365 client, I found a workaround that MFCMapi tool can be used to hide the Clutter folder. Please refer to the following steps:

1. Download the MFCMapi tool from its [official project page](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi/releases/tag/21.0.21127.03) (When you use a 64-bit version of Outlook, you’ll need the file starting with MFCMAPI.x64.exe.);

[image: screenshot]

2. Extract the downloaded zip-file and execute mfcmapi.exe;
3. Accept the dialog prompts to get to the main window of MFCMAPI;
4. Choose Session > Logon > select the profile for which you want to change the mailboxs' display names > ok;
5. Double click the mailbox you want to modify in the upper pane;
6. In the Navigation Pane on the left, expand the folder list called “Root - Mailbox” or “Root Container”;
7. Expand the folder list called “Top Information Store”, “IPM_SUBTREE” or “Top of Outlook data file”;
8. Select the Clutter folder, choose: Property-> Advanced-> Edit given property…

[image: screenshot]

7. Type in Property Tag: 0x10F4000B, and then Property Name will display PR_ATTR_HIDDEN;

[image: screenshot]

8. Click OK;
9. In the Property Editor dialog: select Boolean, and click OK;
10. Close all the open MFCMAPI windows.

And then the Clutter folder should now be hidden in Outlook.
(Notice: To prevent improper operation from damaging mailbox or data loss, please [back up your email data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/back-up-your-email-e5845b0b-1aeb-424f-924c-aa1c33b18833) before doing this operation.)

Comment: Hi @David Christian, Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.